# nfcpy python script printing UID

Tags: python, nfc

I have the following python code that uses nfcpy library which then basically is constantly listening for NFC chip and then it displays the UID using the print syntax. This works perfectly fine. However, I have one issue. If I hold a NFC tag down on the reader, then the script repeats the same card over and over again. Is there a way to not print again and again if it's still the same card being detected?

```
from nfc import ContactlessFrontend
from time import sleep

def connected(tag):
    ident = ''.join('{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in tag.identifier)
    print(ident)
    return False

clf = ContactlessFrontend('usb')
while True:
    clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': connected})
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: You could store the `ident` in a list and then check to see if the ident is already there.  You'd probably want to time out the values periodically.  If this is a production system I'd consider using something like redis where you can store a variable and automatically have it expire after a chosen timeout.

Comment: that sounds like a good way by storing ident into a last scanned list and possibly timing out after X seconds. Any suggestions how I could code that in please?